# Dynamic Data - Success or Failure?

Tags: azure, dynamic-data, rad, lightspeed

Azure, probably ASP.NET Webforms.  We're building a management interface for about 8 tables.  Usual CRUD :-)

2 backend users, and doesn't need to look flash.

We'd like to use Mindscape's [LightSpeed](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/LightSpeed/default.aspx) as the ORM tool

**Question:**  Is Dynamic Data worth pursuing? (Mindscape have a connector to DD).

We've also got the Telerik Suite which is next on the list to check out.

Rapid development here is key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For rapid development, Dynamic Data is great. In its current form it has some good extension points. However, I think you are stuck with either Entity Framework or Linq to SQL for O/RM solutions. Not necessarily a bad thing for an 8 table app, but something to consider.

Comment: Thanks timjmenvdk - LightSpeed does work fine with Dynamic Data.